# SVG width and height not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css, svg

I currently have an SVG file, the standard text at the top is there as follows:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="400px"
     height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="enable-background:new 0 0 400 400;" xml:space="preserve">

.......

</svg>
```

I've tried changing the width and height to 50%, 100%, 10% etc... and in Chrome it just takes up the whole screen, as if it's 100%, no matter what I try. It's as if there is an issue with using percent.

In Internet Explorer, the image doesn't take up the whole page, it's alot smaller at 100%.

I understand that I could place this into a div element and then resize that but this issue is bothering me. Obviously, I want to use percentages to get a responsive layout, which does happen, it just doesn't get any smaller than 100%, whatever I do.

I'm not using an img tag in the html. I'm using an object tag like so:

```
<body>
    <object>
        <embed src="Loading.svg">
    </object>
</body>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: And what size does your `object` element have …?

Comment: I haven't declared a size for it.

Comment: Well then it will most likely have a default size determined by the browser, much like an `iframe` with no width and/or height given does as well.

Comment: Why would you add an SVG inside on an embed inside of an object ? Can't you simply place the svg inside a <div> ?

Comment: I've tried placing it within another div with a specified width, it's no good. The problem seems to be with the SVG itself. 100% width and height continue to make the svg fill the entire screen in Chrome, whereas in IE, it's very small. Using percentages, I still can't get the SVG to scale any lower than 100%, even if I type 10% width and height. I watched a video that used this method and it scaled down perfectly....I've no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: Ok, so after researching and experimenting, I just changed the html code to:                                                                  `<object>
        <embed style="width:100%; height: 100%;" src="Loading.svg">
    </object>`                                                                       and removed width and height from the svg file. It's just so weird that it worked for someone else.